# How to get verb forms of a verb in Spanish language in Python?

Tags: python, nlp

I am working on a project where I have to plug in verb forms of different Spanish verbs into a text. Is there any library that will allow me to do this?
Or is there any CSV file or pdf which I can read into my code and get the verb forms from there? Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try and use [this](https://github.com/ghidinelli/fred-jehle-spanish-verbs/blob/master/jehle_verb_database.csv) as your csv data.

You would have to load the csv file and access it using something like pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

filename = "file.csv"  # filepath here

df = pd.read_csv(filename)
```

You can read more about [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/).